# How to remove first few characters from every 1st line of each json file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to merge all JSON files into a one single JSON file from a folder. I could do my merge. However I would like to remove the some characters of the 1st line in every file to make the entire JSON valid.

```
# Script to combine all jsons but need to remove the closing , at the end

import glob
import re

# read the whole folder
read_files = glob.glob("bus_stop_1012/*.json")

with open("bus_stop_1012/bus_arrival_1012.json", "wb") as outfile:
# this is the beginning of the combined file
outfile.write(' ')

for f in read_files:

    # will append each data file
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:

        outfile.write(infile.read())
        # will have to add , at the end of each element
        outfile.write(',')

# move back 1 character to remove the last , and end the file
outfile.seek(-1,1)
outfile.write(']}')
```

which generates this single JSON file from a example of 2 json files:

```
{"data": [{"time": "2016-03-02 17:45:20 SGT+0800", "result":{
"BusStopID": "1012", 
"Services": [
    {
        "NextBus": {
            "EstimatedArrival": "2016-03-02T17:48:21+08:00", 
            "Feature": "WAB", 
            "Latitude": "1.2871405", 
            "Load": "Seats Available", 
            "Longitude": "103.8456715", 
            "VisitNumber": "1"
        }, 
        "Operator": "SBST", 
        "OriginatingID": "10589", 
        "ServiceNo": "12", 
        "Status": "In Operation", 
        "SubsequentBus": {
            "EstimatedArrival": "2016-03-02T17:56:02+08:00", 
            "Feature": "WAB", 
            "Latitude": "0", 
            "Load": "Seats Available", 
            "Longitude": "0", 
            "VisitNumber": "1"
        }, 
        "SubsequentBus3": {
            "EstimatedArrival": "2016-03-02T18:06:02+08:00", 
            "Feature": "WAB", 
            "Latitude": "0", 
            "Load": "Seats Available", 
            "Longitude": "0", 
            "VisitNumber": "1"
        }, 
        "TerminatingID": "77009"
    }
], 
"odata.metadata":
"http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/$metadata#BusArrival/@Element"
}},{"data": [{"time": "2016-03-02 17:49:36 SGT+0800", "result":{
"BusStopID": "1012", 
"Services": [
    {
        "NextBus": {
            "EstimatedArrival": "2016-03-02T17:48:47+08:00", 
            "Feature": "WAB", 
            "Latitude": "1.2944553333333333", 
            "Load": "Seats Available", 
            "Longitude": "103.85045283333334", 
            "VisitNumber": "1"
        }, 
        "Operator": "SBST", 
        "OriginatingID": "10589", 
        "ServiceNo": "12", 
        "Status": "In Operation", 
        "SubsequentBus": {
            "EstimatedArrival": "2016-03-02T17:58:26+08:00", 
            "Feature": "WAB", 
            "Latitude": "1.2821243333333334", 
            "Load": "Seats Available", 
            "Longitude": "103.841401", 
            "VisitNumber": "1"
        }, 
        "SubsequentBus3": {
            "EstimatedArrival": "2016-03-02T18:06:02+08:00", 
            "Feature": "WAB", 
            "Latitude": "0", 
            "Load": "Seats Available", 
            "Longitude": "0", 
            "VisitNumber": "1"
        }, 
        "TerminatingID": "77009"
    }
    ], 
"odata.metadata":     "http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/$metadata#BusArrival/@Element"
}}]}
```

I would need the **{"data": [** of each subsequent JSON file to be removed as it is found in every JSON file.

Comment: So why not decode from JSON, extract the data you do want to export to the new file, and re-encode?

Comment: Just to expand on that, blindly assuming any and every JSON file has this haphazard formatting is a brittle and unsound approach in the general case. However, in your specific case, you may be able to get away with that - or even need to, if your input isn't actually well-formed JSON. But then your question's title isn't really representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decode from JSON, extract the elements you want, then write those out as JSON again.

If the goal is to produce one large `{"data": [....]}` list, you can get away with writing each element in the list separately if you take care not to write a last comma:

```
import glob
import json

# read the whole folder
read_files = glob.glob("bus_stop_1012/*.json")

with open("bus_stop_1012/bus_arrival_1012.json", "wb") as outfile:
    # this is the beginning of the combined file
    outfile.write('{"data": [\n')
    sep = ''
    for f in read_files:
        # will append each data file
        with open(f) as infile:
             try:
                for obj in json.load(infile)['data']:
                    outfile.write(sep)
                    json.dump(obj, outfile)
                    sep = ','
             except ValueError:
                 print 'Failed to load {}'.format(f)
    outfile.write(']}')
```

Comment: Did the change and it returned me with a new error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combine_bus_arrivals.py", line 14, in <module>
    for obj in json.load(infile)['data']:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
   ** kw)
  File

Comment: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: You appear to have a file that isn't properly JSON formatted or is empty.

Comment: @TimothyLey: you could put a `try: ... except ValueError:` around the block and log what files are having problems, but you can't force a broken file to be loaded otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Martijin. Codes had no problems, my files were not in JSON format.